# Why does my query still do a full table scan with sortkey in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

Let's say we have a table table1 with field1 INT ENCODE ZSTD, and we added interleaved sort key on field1.

But when I do the query `select * from table1 where field1=123;`, I still see a sequential scan on the whole table which I suppose should be a sub scan on the table.

Do I have some misunderstanding about sort key?

Answer (score 3):

1) From what you tell, you don't need an interleaved sort key because you have just one column you're interested in. You need an interleaved sort key when you want multiple columns to be equally important because you want to run both `where col1=123` and `where col2=123` kind of queries. This provides benefit for large tables.

2) Compressing your sort key column is considered a bad practice. [Proof from Amazon](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/top-10-performance-tuning-techniques-for-amazon-redshift/): `the first column in a compound sort key should not be encoded` (one column key is the same). The entire article is actually useful, read it and you won't regret

3) When sort key is configured and data is populated it's better to run vacuum and analyze commands to make sure rows are sorted accordingly to sort key and table statistics are updated.

Comment: There are more fields there. Just a little lazy to put all of them here. (we have over 100 columns)

Comment: I don't think I need a compound sort key since it's not always the same pattern to do my query.

And also vacuum and analyze have been run before.

Comment: Alex is wise. Listen to Alex. :) Or read our "Advanced Table Design Playbook" for more detailed explanations. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/amazon-redshift-engineerings-advanced-table-design-playbook-preamble-prerequisites-and-prioritization/